# Google Deployment Manager Resource types for cloud endpoints

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, google-deployment-manager

I've been looking for a way of including cloud endpoints in my deployment configuration, but it doesn't seem there is any resource type for Cloud Endpoints.

My Google Deployment config will contain:

- 1 vm compute instance
- 1 network
- 1 firewall rule
- 1 cloud endpoint 1
- 1 cloud sql instance (mysql)

The config_id generated from the newly deployed cloud endpoint will need to be applied to the vm's meta-data.  So utilizing template references would seem the ideal route to go.

But like I said, there doesn't seem be any cloud endpoint resource type.  I could be wrong.  If not, what is the best approach to get around this?

Thanks

Comment: You are [actually right](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/supported-resource-types), you might want to file a [feature request](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I'm under a deadline right now.  Would the honorable service minded Googler like to put in a feature request on my behalf?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Deploy Manager does not support yet Cloud Endopints. You can check here [1] the accepted resource types.

Also I went ahead and I have opened a public feature request [2] where you can check the status of it. Keep in mind that there is no ETA no guaranty this feature will be implemented.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/supported-resource-types
[2] https://issuetracker.google.com/74311417